# Set angular ui grid dropdown list width

Tags: html, css, angularjs, pagination, angular-ui-grid

I have a ui grid in which i am using pagination. 
paginationSizes : [25, 50, 75 ,100]
On selecting 100 in the ui-grid dropdownlist, 100 doesnot gets diplayed fully.
How do i use CSS to change the the width of the shown dropdownlist.
Thanks :) 
This is currently my grid options :

```
`$scope.gridOptions = { 
                    enableFiltering: true,
                    enablePaging: true,
                    enableRowSelection: true,
                    multiSelect: false,
                    paginationPageSizes: [25, 50, 100],
                    paginationPageSize: 10

                };`
```

[Screenshot of my ui-grid dropdownlist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DiS2p.jpg)

Comment: Set CSS property like : .ui-grid-pager-row-count-picker select { width: 100px !important; }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set following CSS style property in your custom css file

```
.ui-grid-pager-row-count-picker select 
{ 
  width: 100px !important; 
}
```